# jqueryUI selectable with AngularJS not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, angularjs

i'm trying to know why my code isn't working with the selectable, im including the libraries

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

This is the code that would have the selectable items in the list

```
<div class="modal-wrapper">
    <ul id="selectable" class="data-list">
        <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="data in testData">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="container-title">
                        <span class="inner-title">{{data.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="container-subtitle">
                        <span class="subtitle">{{data.title}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bottom-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-wizard" ng-click="alertSelected()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this is the little piece of code for the selectable:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('im there');    
        }       
    }); 
});
```

And this is my current css for this test:

```
body{
    background-color: #231f20 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-wrapper {
    width: 564px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}


.list-item {
    background-color: #555;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 16px 10px 15px;
}

.container-title {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-title {
    position: relative;
    top: 54px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.container-subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
}

.subtitle {
    position: relative;
    color: #333;
}

.bottom-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 564px;
}

.btn-wizard {
    position: relative;
    left: 230px;
    top: 17px;
    width: 100px !important;
}

 #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
 #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

Any ideas on what's going? is it a CSS problem? or the `<li>` structure?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where did you place your references?

Comment: Are you getting errors in your dev console? Are you testing this locally or with a server?

Comment: no errors on console, tried that, maybe there might be an error in there of a non-recognized variable or function from jquery to give me a clue, but nope, no errors, looks like its being imported. Now... the selectable isn't working for some reason :(

Comment: yes @яша it's there, included

Comment: omg, nothing is working when i add functionality to ul's, to ids, anything works! not even a on('mouseenter', function() {});... nothing works! what's happening T_T i'm adding my main.js into the index, so it's not that either.

Comment: you want to add some events on selectable elements ?

Comment: yes, but nothing is working dunno what's going on, not even a hover event in the li is working, something weird is happening! :@

Comment: that is right the `selectable` wont work in your situation because the list is created dynamically and jqueryui runs before the dome is created. I don't have much experience with `angularjs`, I use `knockoutjs` in `ko` I normaly use `bindinghandler` i think in `ng` it's called `Custom Directives`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit js/controllers/myWorkController.js

```
portfolioApp.controller('myWorkController', function($scope) {
    $scope.testData = [
        {
            name : "Test 1",
            title : "Home"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 2",
            title : "About"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 3",
            title : "Contact"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 4",
            title : "Join"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 4",
            title : "Join"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 4",
            title : "Join"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 4",
            title : "Join"
        },
        {
            name : "Test 4",
            title : "Join"
        },      
    ];

    $scope.alertSelected = function() {
        /* alert it ! */ 
    };
    $('#selectable').selectable();
});
```

Comment: worked for you? :O i was trying now to use a directive, let me check something first, otherwise i will use that one.

Comment: OMG!!!! I MADE IT WORK THANKS TO YOU! :') just added in the link inside the directive this code link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   $timeout(function() {
    if(!scope.$$phase) {
     $('#selectable').selectable(); 
     scope.$apply();
    }
   },0);   
  } to avoid diggest issues and stuff and it WORKED AWESOMELY!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Jqueryui [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) regarding selectable you can only implement your code in the meaning of `<li>` wrapped by `<ul> or <ol>` syntax  as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zxrLf/)

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

if you want to add any hover event to the `<li>` elements add this code to your script:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    $(".list-item").hover(function() {
    alert("hovered!")
}, function() {
    alert("unhovered!")
});
  });
```

Comment: not even a hover event in the li is working, something weird is happening! :@ but a console.log('random') works on the main.js, it's importing the js but not paying attention to any jquery function.

Comment: nothing works! :@ don't know what's wrong with this project, nothing seems to work, not even the example provided by jquery itself! can't find the bug on my little test project.

Comment: Yea, that one is working, but i don't know why mine isn't :'(

Comment: lol tried to jsfiddle my code and kinda works :S might be a problem with angularJS? the only difference is that in the jsfiddle haven't used angular. My god :/

Comment: why are you using ng-repeat ? are you using angular.js ? it might be conflicting with your code try to disable it and see if it works

Comment: so it is working without implementing Angular.js in your code?

Comment: Haven't tested but i believe it should work without angularJS, tested it with jsfiddle. But i need to make it work with AngularJS, no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You must know selectable will select the nested child

```
$("#selectable").selectable();
```

will select "li", I find your code have one "li", you must add more li to ul
if you want select div class "row", try that:

```
$(".list-item").selectable();
```

Comment: not working either :( if i mistype selectable to selectabl or example, it shows an error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectabl' so the son of a b**** is getting into the jquery code. Don't know why it's not working. Could be a problem of my div? i mean i got a div inside those list items...

Comment: yeah i know, don't know what's wrong with this... in my code doesn't work where i use angularJS and ng-repeat.

Comment: open by Chrome, Press F12 and refesh page, Then take me a screenshot of the console

Comment: You must drag mouse to selecttable before take a screenshot. (the error will be show)

Comment: no matter what i click or where i put my mouse on, it doesn't show any error :/

Comment: Upload yourcode and send me the link. I will help you to debug

Comment: You use portfolioApp.controller to load template, so you need call event selectTable after controller load completd. See my answer below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778339/jqueryui-selectable-with-angularjs-not-working-for-me/20778929#20778929

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

change to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And why should he do this?